# Why isn't my paper mill being provided with lumber?

Tags: anno-1404, anno-1404-venice

I built a Paper Mill awhile ago (top left structure in the below image, over the river), and I just noticed that it's not being provided with any lumber. As you can see from my image it's within the radius of the market building (bottom right), but it's not being provided with lumber. I've verified that the market is reachable by road, and I've got over 100 lumber in storage.

[image: market radius]

Why isn't my Paper Mill being provided with Lumber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So turns out the issue is that the radius of the market only indicates the *pick up* range for goods. To determine if a production building will be supplied with goods you need to check it's individual radius, as shown here:

[image: paper mill radius too small]

It's this radius around the production building itself that determines if a production building will be supplied with goods. The radius of the market (or other supply buildings) doesn't actually matter. As you can in the image, the market is just outside the range of the paper mill, so that's why it's not getting any lumber. After destroying the market and rebuilding it like below, my paper mill immediately was supplied with lumber.

[image: paper mill radius fine]

Interestingly enough a cart didn't actually transfer the lumber, but it was instead transferred by an NPC carrying lumber. So carts must only be used for the pickup of goods, and the transfer of goods to a production building  uses generic NPCs.

Comment: Footnote: I'm sure this was explained in the campaign, but since that's not actually playable if you boot the game up with the Venice expansion, I didn't even realize the campaign  *existed* until a couple hours ago.